# Loop Calculation Across Multiple Sublists

Tags: r, list, loops, data-manipulation

I have a set of coordinate data for mice moving in an arena, with each trial having its own data frame. For each file, I want to calculate how far away the mouse is at a given time point (frame) from a set object (in this case, an odor spot). The location of the odor spot changes with each trial. Because of the nature of other analyses in the pipeline, at this point I have the data frames for the values I need in a list.

Here's example data to show the structure of the list I'm working with, using random sham data.

```
#These data frames mimic the structure of the coordinate data (main variables of interest are frame, x, y)
df1 <- data.frame(frame = seq(1:50), 
                 x = runif(50, min=1, max=90), 
                 y = runif(50, min=1, max=90))
df2 <- data.frame(frame = seq(1:50),
           x = runif(50, min=1, max=90), 
           y = runif(50, min=1, max=90))
#These data frames mimic the structure of the coordinates of the non-moving locations (i.e. odorspot, arena corners. While the only location I'm interested in is the odorspot ("os"), I'm showing this with other coordinate locations because that is how the data is structured after my other processing steps)
med1 <- data.frame(pointname = c("tl", "tr", "bl", "br", "os", "cs"),
                  x = runif(6, min=1, max=90),
                  y = runif(6, min=1, max=90))
med2 <- data.frame(pointname = c("tl", "tr", "bl", "br", "os", "cs"),
                   x = runif(6, min=1, max=90),
                   y = runif(6, min=1, max=90))

datalist <- list(data1 = df1, 
             data2 = df2)
medlist <- list(data1 = med1,
                data2 = med2)
#Example of the list structure
biglist <- list(data = datalist, 
                median.data = medlist)
```

So for each of the "data" dataframes, I want to add a new column called DistSpot, that is the calculation of how far the mouse is away from the odor spot at each frame.

The end data should look something like this:

```
  frame        x        y SpotDist
1     0 41.18153 84.49540 66.88208
2     1 41.18153 84.51059 66.89718
3     2 41.18153 84.54423 66.93062
4     3 41.03425 84.64317 67.01337
5     4 40.96008 84.93739 67.29827
6     5 40.70080 85.17731 67.51068
```

For biglist$data$data1, the corresponding odor spot coordinate would be found in biglist$median.data$data1[5,2] (fifth row, second column)

I tried to write a loop function to do the calculation, but it is not running (gives error on closure type). I'm also not sure if I'm calling the median.data variable correctly.

```
DistanceOdor <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x$data)){
    x$data[i]$diffx <- (x$data[i]$x - x$median.data[5,2])^2 
    x$data[i]$diffy <- (x$data[i]$y - x$median.data[5,3])^2
    x$data[i]$distspot <- sqrt(x$data[i]$diffx + x$data[i]$diffy)
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, you can `Map` over your different inputs and then calculate the Euclidean distance with `transform`. For example

```
Map(function(pos, ref) { 
  os <- subset(ref, pointname=="os")
  transform(pos, SpotDist = sqrt((x-os$x)^2 + (y-os$y)^2))
}, biglist$data, biglist$median.data)
# $data1
#    frame         x         y  SpotDist
# 1      1 54.588150 60.336306 50.926487
# 2      2 18.358910 64.556675 31.570075
# 3      3 87.014827 69.396838 83.830691
# 4      4 58.930592 84.829107 69.916124
# ...
# $data2
#    frame         x         y SpotDist
# 1      1 68.006640 27.077371 77.26383
# 2      2 76.747999 68.794598 75.35945
# 3      3 76.288808 58.011732 75.31435
# 4      4  9.879642 81.893493 17.74808
# ...
```

These are the values I get if I run `set.seed(15)` before the code you provided.

If you wanted to use your function, you need to be more careful with `[]` vs `[[]]`. Use the former to subset a list and use the latter to extract items from a list. You could do

```
DistanceOdor <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x$data)){
    x$data[[i]]$diffx <- (x$data[[i]]$x - x$median.data[[i]][5,2])^2 
    x$data[[i]]$diffy <- (x$data[[i]]$y - x$median.data[[i]][5,3])^2
    x$data[[i]]$distspot <- sqrt(x$data[[i]]$diffx + x$data[[i]]$diffy)
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!
And thanks for the note with the brackets. I originally had them double bracketed, but I still got the error. Must have had another typo somewhere, cause copying your code works.

Comment: You were also missing the double bracket index on the `x$median.data` values.